# How to get the parameters that was defined in mule-app.properties when running as Tomcat app?

Tags: tomcat, parameters, mule

I finally got my Mule app running in Tomcat. But I ran into one issue and need your help.

I don't know where to put the mule-app.properties and mule-deploy.properties files. 
I have some parameters like db name, driver name, url, etc. in mule-app.properties file. I tried to put them 
 - in the class path /WEB-INF/lib or /WEB-INF/classes
 - direct under /WEB-INF
 - under /WEB-INF/src/main/app or under /WEB-INF/src/mail/resources
 - right next to WEB-INF
but none of them works. I cannot get them from the flow using EL and I cannot get them from java using the MuleRegistry object.

Please help me to get the parameters from mule-app.properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mule-app.properties` and `mule-deploy.properties` files are only loaded by Mule Standalone.

Since you run in embedded mode:

- `mule-deploy.properties` is meaningless: drop it,
- you need to load `mule-app.properties` with Spring's `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties" />`. Put `mule-app.properties` in `src/main/resources` so when Maven builds your web-app it ends in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Do you mind accepting it then? It's kind of the way things work here at StackOverflow. If you don't accept any answer, the question will remain open for ever. And I won't get any credit for the good answer either.

Comment: David, sorry, didn't know I need to accept it. Your help is very much appreciated.